# How to find the BLE beacon location from RSSI values

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I havea project using BLE beacons and ble gateways to track the beacon location. Is there any way to find the exact location of ble beacons from rssi values?

Please guide me a solution or any SDK or API

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. RSSI gives you the power of the signal. The best you can do is deduce the distance.

I had a similar project. I used several distance measures at known position to trilaterate the position of the target.

I don't know your language, but I used flutter_beacon.

Comment: Update: you cannot get location from one value. You have to get distance from rssi values and use these distance to deduce the value. But it requires to get someway your position.

Comment: We use reactjs for frontend development. could you please share the details of methods you used?